# Is this Linq query a currect way to retrieve data or there are more effective ways?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

This code works but I've heard from somewhere that when we use Select    it pushes to execute Join operation. So will it considered a slow    operation, or by the way is there a way/ program to check linq    queries correctness, performance ...

```
public IQueryable<Entity> GetById(int id){return_context.Set<Entity().Where(p => p.Id == id);}

var actor = _repository.GetById(id)
    .Select(a => new 
    { 
        a.Id,
        a.FirstName, 
        a.LastName, 
        a.Bio, 
        a.Birthday, 
        a.Height, 
        a.Image,    
        Country = new 
        {
            a.Country.Id, 
            a.Country.Name 
        }, 
        Movies = a.ActorMovies
            .Select(am => new 
            {
                am.Movie.Title,
                am.Movie.Year,
                am.Movie.Image 
            })
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Log the SQL query that EF generates to see if it includes a JOIN clause or not.

Comment: for one, we have no clue on what `_repository.GetById(id)` do. what are available indexes for the dbms? additionally, what else you have tried? you can use profiler or something to see time spent running the query. also, `Select` doesn't necessarily cause `join` you can get subquery instead. don't forget you can use `Include` to preload relationship too.

Comment: Your query is fine. But also try to add `AsSplitQuery()` it may perform better in Eager Loading query - Movies will be loaded separatelly.

Comment: Note that using joins are not necessarily slow or inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that query will use a join -- not because it's written in LINQ, but because you specifically *ask* it to join to another table (in setting the `Movies` property).  There's no way I can see it get that result (efficiently) without using the join.

However, there is a problem with that code.  I'm assuming that this is taken from your business layer.  Actually, almost all of that should be in the repository.  Your only line in the business layer should be:

```
var actor = _repository.GetActorWithMoviesById(id);
```